# VBA macro specific to Excel 64bit

Tags: vba, excel, 64-bit

I want to write some macro specific to Excel 64 bit., 
the below link says about a macro, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264421.aspx

But it says "#if Win64" : Whether it reffers excatly office version..? because Users can install Office 32 bit 2010 in Windows 64 bit OS.

Comment: The page says, the Win64 constant tells you what version of office your vba code is running on. A 32-bit office cannot make use of any 64-bit functionality and 64-bit office cannot be installed on a 32-bit machine. To my mind, all relevant questions are covered with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it says "#if Win64" : Whether it reffers excatly office version..?
>   because Users can install Office 32 bit 2010 in Windows 64 bit OS.

The Win64 constant used within a #If...then...#Else is a [compiler constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264614.aspx). If it returns true, it indicates that the development environment is 64-bit compatible. Which means code written for a 32-bit environment may have issues.

In general the only conflict you may encounter between 32 bit VBA and 64 bit VBA is if you attempt to call outside Dlls via Declare. As described in the link you provided, the primary potential issue is this:

> The problem with running legacy VBA code in 64-bit Office is that
>   trying to load 64-bits into a 32-bit data type truncates the 64-bit
>   quantity. This can result in memory overruns, unexpected results in
>   your code, and possible application failure.

Probably your legacy code would still work, but you make the adjustment to assure that it will work.

The method of handling this is described in the link you provided where you provide the correct calling method for 64-bit within the #If...then...#Else structure using the compiler constants.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of confirming because, i have an application that installs my custom dll based on office bitness. So, i want to write VBA according to Office's bitness. then, the answer to my question is  "#if Win64" - is true for only 64 bit office and false for 32 bit office in 64 bit OS.

Comment: According to the documentation, yes. They didn't write it very obviously, but it's a little more clear in the link I provided. What they actually list is this: Constant: Win64 Value: False Description: Indicates that the development environment is not 64-bit compatible.